# getBlock returns bool(false) on production server - on staging it returns an Object

Tags: magento

I created a Controller with a block in it and when I call getBlock I get bool(false) in return:

```
$block = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('somestuff_index');
```

AND:

```
var_dump($block); // -> bool(false)
```

Usually it should return an Object!

There is one thing which makes everything weird. On the staging server it works (!!) and on the production server it fails. Both environments are nearly the same, except that the production server uses memcaching.

The Controller doesnt get cached, this is sure! But still the error remains...

Any Experience with this kind of error?

Help please

Comment: Clear every cache you have and give it an other try. The layout file might be cached

Comment: Please check any block is available or not

Comment: what is class of block???

Comment: Thanks guys, after every live deploy I clear all caches. Nothing worked...

Comment: @ Amit - I already checked if the head block is available and it is! Only "my" created block isnt available and return no object

Comment: @ Amit - the class is as usual: class Name_SomeStuff_Block_Index extends Mage_Core_Block_Template{ Did you mean that?

Comment: Did you ever find the solution? I am facing the same problem.

Comment: I didnt find a clear solution, I just made a workaround on working with blocks and put the code of the Block into the .phtml file, so everything looks the same. It isnt the nicest solution but it works

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/38491/missing-blocks-on-live-system had a similar problem, says it was because of a URL rewrite error.