# Magento Fatal Error

Tags: php, magento, installation, append, fatal-error

Its my first try with Magento.

I get this Error Message:

Fatal error: Call to a member function append() on a non-object in /var/customers/webs/magento/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Install/controllers/WizardController.php on line 77

Maybe someone have an Idee or can help me with my Problem?

Now the whole Code from Line 68 - 79:

```
    protected function _prepareLayout()
{
    $this->loadLayout('install_wizard');
    $step = $this->_getWizard()->getStepByRequest($this->getRequest());
    if ($step) {
        $step->setActive(true);
    }

    $leftBlock = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('install/state', 'install.state');
    $this->getLayout()->getBlock('left')->append($leftBlock);
    return $this;
}
```

Its the orginal code i haven´t edit anything

Comment: I have edit my Post, now the code is added

Comment: your getBlock() function doesn't return an object. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21157766/getblock-returns-boolfalse-on-production-server-on-staging-it-returns-an-obj

Comment: The return is in the next Line.

Comment: are you sure you have all the files? The error appears because `$this->getLayout()->getBlock('left')` returns `null` for some reason. Maybe you are missing a layout file or something.

Comment: The Problem was some Files are not uploadet by FileZilla. After a check I saw 14 Files are not uploadet.
Thank You @Marius

Answer (score 0):

$this->getLayout()->getBlock('left')

should return a block class or NULL.

If it returned a block class then :
abstract class Mage_Core_Block_Abstract extends Varien_Object
has function

append($leftBlock);

This means that your $this->getLayout()->getBlock('left')
 is not return a block instance.

Why not do a mage log of what $this->getLayout()->getBlock('left')
returns and confirm.